# Detect character position in an UTF NSString from a byte offset(was SQLite offsets() and encoding problem)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

**Short story**:
I have an UTF NSString and a byte offset. I want to know the character at that byte offset. How can I do?

Below is the long story if you dare:

According [this](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_1) documentation *offsets*() function returns byte offset inside a column of a term. I have indexed some text and I use that offset to point to a particular section of the text when I display results.

Crucial problem is that using this byte offset I am unable to point the right location of the term. Sometimes it points correctly, sometimes it is 3/4 chars away from right point.

My table is very simple:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t1 USING fts4(file, body, page);
```

If I do a query such as:

```
SELECT page, body, offsets(t1) from t1 where body match 'and';
```

I receive:

```
...........
502|1 0 427 3
505|1 0 370 3 1 0 1307 3 1 0 1768 3
506|1 0 10 3 1 0 1861 3 1 0 2521 3

...........
```

As an example if I point to char 427 of body I don't get the right position of 'and' but I jump 2/3 chars away from it. The same if I go to 370 and if I go instead to 10 I get the right position.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Sqlite FTS3 docs](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_1) and you'll notice that the offsets and lengths are in *bytes* not characters.

You must apply the offset and length before decoding the bytes into a string of characters in order to display the correct offset. The offset coming from Sqlite counts each byte of multibyte characters, whereas you are using that offset to count *characters*.

Your indexed text probably has 3 or 4 characters that are two bytes. Hence the off-by-3-or-4 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per @metatation's answer, the offset is in bytes, not characters. The text in your database is probably UTF8-encoded Unicode, in which case any single non-ASCII **character** is represented by multiple **bytes**. Examples of non-ASCII characters include those with accents (à, ö, etc), smart quotes, characters from non-Latin character sets (Greek, Cyrillic, most Asian character sets, etc) and so on.

If the bytes in the SQLite database are UTF8-encoded Unicode strings you can work out the true Unicode character offset for a given byte offset like so:

```
NSUInteger characterOffsetForByteOffsetInUTF8String(NSUInteger byteOffset, const char *string) {
    /*
     * UTF-8 represents ASCII characters in a single byte. Characters with a code
     * point from U+0080 upwards are represented as multiple bytes. The first byte
     * always has the two most significant bits set (i.e. 11xxxxxx). All subsequent
     * bytes have the most significant bit set, the next most significant bit unset
     * (i.e. 10xxxxxx).
     * 
     * We use that here to determine character offsets. We step through the first
     * `byteOffset` bytes of `string`, incrementing the character offset result
     * every time we come across a byte that doesn't match 10xxxxxx, i.e. where
     * (byte & 11000000) != 10000000
     *
     * See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description
     */
    NSUInteger characterOffset = 0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < byteOffset; i++) {
        char c = string[i];
        if ((c & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
            characterOffset++;
        }
    }
    return characterOffset;
}
```

Caveat: If you're using the character offset to index into an `NSString`, bear in mind that `NSString` uses UTF-16 under the hood, so characters with a Unicode code point higher than U+FFFF are represented by a *pair* of 16-bit values. You generally won't bump up against this for text content, but if you care about particularly obscure character sets, or some of the non-text characters Unicode can represent such as Emojis, then the above algorithm will require improvements to cater for those.

(The code snippet's from [this project of mine](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/wwdc-session-search/blob/develop/WWDC%20Session%20Search/SWMainWindowController.m) - feel free to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this thread, and Simon's solution in particular; here's how I do it.

There might be a more "Swifty" way than returning an `NSRange` but I need it to highlight an `NSAttributedString`.

```
extension String {

    func charRangeForByteRange(range : NSRange) -> NSRange {

        let bytes = [UInt8](utf8)

        var charOffset = 0

        for i in 0..<range.location {
            if ((bytes[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) { charOffset++ }
        }

        let location = charOffset

        for i in range.location..<(range.location + range.length) {
            if ((bytes[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) { charOffset++ }
        }

        let length = charOffset - location

        return NSMakeRange(location, length)
    }
}
```