# How to convert the byte offset from sqlite FTS query into a character offset in java

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, unicode

I have a problem where I am searching my FTS tables in android and I get returned a byte offset for the result :

```
col     termno      byteoffset      size
1       0           111             4
```

However problem is, when using `cursor.getString(colNo)` it gives me a UTF-16 string after which I am unable to tally up which character of the text is the start/end of the match.

Its a similar problem to : [Detect character position in an UTF NSString from a byte offset(was SQLite offsets() and encoding problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407284/detect-character-position-in-an-utf-nsstring-from-a-byte-offsetwas-sqlite-offse)

However I cannot fathom the solution in the question. So how can I accurately know the character offsets in my string (for highlight) after I know the byte offsets?

Answer (score 4):

Encode your string back to the same encoding that Sqlite was using, then extract the pieces you want in byte form and convert them back to strings:

```
String chars = cursor.getString(colNo);
byte[] bytes = chars.getBytes("UTF-8");
String prefix = new String(bytes, 0, byteOffset, "UTF-8");
String match = new String(bytes, byteOffset, size, "UTF-8");
int charOffset = prefix.length;
int charSize = match.length;
```

(Assuming that your data is encoded as UTF-8 bytes, which is probable.)

It is unfortunate that you have to do all this redundant encoding and decoding. It might perhaps be worth adding optimisations to short-cut the pure-ASCII common case.

Comment: You know I had just figured out exactly the same thing and thought to myself what a pain. Glad you made the same suggestion.